# Div below with fixed height, div above filling the remaning vertical space?

Tags: css, html

How do I create a div that has a fixed height and stays on the bottom of the page, and another one above it occupying the remaining vertical space?

Comment: bottom of the page as in page content or bottom of the browser?

Comment: Are you looking for a [Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) type of effect?

Comment: @KMC like this: http://o7.no/YWOhDF I just want the blue block to fill 400px below everything, while the other 2 divs fill the remaining space.

Comment: @IanGregory the example of that page is bad because the footer is resized instead of the rest of the page when it's too small.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://cssdesk.com/3H8H7) should achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/53r5z/)

Use height: inherit for your first div which takes the remaining height available

html

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='first'>
    First Div content
</div>
    <div id='second'>
        Second div content
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
#container{
width: 600px;
height: 450px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
#second{
position: relative;
bottom: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: green;
}  
#first{
height: inherit;
background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the other examples really work nicely when the page is resized.

This type of thing is best accomplished with a few lines of javascript, as its not something that CSS does a great job of generally speaking.

See here for a working demo.  mod.it requires that you view the demo in chrome but the code in the demo is cross browser and will work anywhere.

https://mod.it/6hQaRsEL